# Regex group being too greedy

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract CONTENT from two different string formats

Example one

> {new=[[CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT]], mod=[], del=[]}

Example two

> {new=[[CONTENT]], mod=[], del=[]}

I have tried the following regex, but it's being too greedy and does not work for both formats.

```
{new=\[(\[.*\])(, |)\], mod=\[\], del=\[\]\}
```

What regex is needed to match both examples and put CONTENT into match groups?

Comment: This has nothing to do with greediness. What is the regex engine you are using? What is the programming language? Use your regex, grab Group 1 contents, trim from `[` and `]`, and split with `], [`.

Comment: @Wiktor I'm using Java

Comment: Great, then use `\{new=\[\[(.*)\](, |)\], mod=\[\], del=\[\]\}` and split `m.group(1)` with `\], \[` regex. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/wlf19I).

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/wlf19I (and http://ideone.com/yMSB95).

Comment: Works perfectly thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest moving the capturing parentheses around `.*`, then grab Group 1 contents and split with `\], \[` pattern:

```
String s = "{new=[[CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT], [CONTENT]], mod=[], del=[]}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{new=\\[\\[(.*)\\](, |)\\], mod=\\[\\], del=\\[\\]\\}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
String[] res = null;
if (m.find()){
    res = m.group(1).split("\\], \\[");
} 
if (res != null) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res)); 
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/wlf19I)